# Turn two gorm queries into one

Tags: go, go-gorm

I have the following models

```
type Instance struct {
    gorm.Model
    Name               string `gorm:"index:idx_name_and_group,unique"`
    UserID             uint
    GroupID            uint `gorm:"index:idx_name_and_group,unique"`
    ...
}

type Group struct {
    gorm.Model
    Name                 string `gorm:"unique;"`
    Instances            []Instance
    ...
}
```

I'm trying to get an instance by name and group name.

I can do it using the following code

```
func (r instanceRepository) FindByName(groupName string, instanceName string) (*model.Instance, error) {
    var instance *model.Instance
    var group *model.Group

    err := r.db.
        First(&group, "name = ?", groupName).Error
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }

    err = r.db.
        Where("name = ? and group_id = ?", instanceName, group.ID).
        First(&instance).Error

    return instance, err
}
```

But I'd like to turn it into one query. Any ideas about how to achieve that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can always use the [Joins](https://gorm.io/docs/query.html#Joins) function to do SQL joins. Something like this:

```
func (r instanceRepository) FindByName(groupName string, instanceName string) (*model.Instance, error) {
    var instance *model.Instance

    err := r.db.
        Joins("INNER JOIN groups g ON g.id = instances.group_id").
        Where("g.name = ? AND instances.name = ?", groupName, instanceName).
        First(&instance).Error
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }

    return instance, err
}
```